# <Link> component in NextJS seems to lose the cursor-pointer with a <div> as child component

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using NextJS and wanted to configure a top navigation header bar. In the left-hand side of my nav bar, I have a small svg and text that I would like to be Link's to the site's root. The Link component will not allow multiple children, so I have done this:

```
<Link href="/">
  <div className="">
    <img className="" src="/whistle.svg" />
    <span className="">Root!</span>
  </div>
</Link>
```

however, when I do this the entire div block loses it cursor-pointer and I need to then set a specific class of cursor pointer. I am also using tailwindCSS. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here in this instance - any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<Link>` [must have](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) `<a>` tag inside. You define your styles by yourself, so just add cursor pointer `class` of `style` to your `div`. You can add `className="cursor-pointer"` to your div instead of the style described.

```
<Link href="/">
  <a>
  <div className="" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
    <a>
    <img className="" src="/whistle.svg" />
    <span className="">Root!</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </a>
</Link>
```

P.S. Update for 2023+, and for Nextjs v13+ : `<Link>` **should not need** `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`next/link` no longer requires manually adding  as a child:

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#nextlink

```
import Link from 'next/link'

// Before
// Next.js 12: `<a>` has to be nested otherwise it's excluded
<Link href="/about">
  <a>About</a>
</Link>

// Next.js 13: `<Link>` always renders `<a>`
<Link href="/about">
  About
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to be an issue in Next.js 13... also using tailwind, so it could be a side effect of having all styles reset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34933708)